# How to get XCode 4.2 to recognize custom property list structure definitions?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, structure, definition

I have downloaded and installed PlistEdit Pro to help create custom property list structure definition files so that I can predefine a list of possible drop down selections to make it easier for the person editing the plist and also make it less prone to error.

I have successfully made a structure definition file, but currently, the only way I can edit the plist using the def file is through PlistEdit Pro.

Is there a way I can get Xcode to recognize the def file, so that I can edit the plist using my custom drop downs through XCode? (Similar to how XCode recognizes the info.plist xcodeplugin definition file)

I have placed the file under many different Plug-in folders located through out my Mac and none seem to work:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns

~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins

Comment: Anyone? I don't mean to spam, but I think this would be a great answer for a lot of people if this is possible. I am surprised I can't find more people wanting the same thing.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Pterie Daktyl Nope, not yet.

Answer (score 2):

I found a good answer compatible with XCode 4.5.x after a little digging.  The problems are twofold with the PListEdit Pro capability: the plugin directories have changed and the plugin file format has changed.   Thankfully, github and AliSoftware to the rescue:

https://github.com/AliSoftware/xcodeplugin

This is an xslt conversion utility to go from .xcodeplugin to .dvtplugin (the new format).  So basically you can author your property list definition in PListEdit Pro and save to .xcodeplugin, then run xcpc to convert and install the plugin.

Note that there are at least one or two incompatible extensions that PListEdit Pro adds in that will blow up xcpc - but the basic functionality is fine.

Another note: the documentation for xcodeplugin leaves out how to associate a property list type with a file format.  PListEdit Pro doesn't seem to support doing this, but you can manually add the following to your .xcodeplugin:

```
<plugin ...>
  <extension ...>
    <filename pattern="*cases.plist" />
    ...
```